# Derivate in order to a string

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, string-manipulation, expression-manipulation

So I have the following expression:

```
Gain = (20 Log[Abs[("Rout")/(
   "Rin" + "Rout" + 2 I "L1" f \[Pi] + 2 I "L3" f \[Pi] + 
    2 I "C2" "Rin" "Rout" f \[Pi] - 4 "C2" "L3" "Rin" f^2 \[Pi]^2 - 
    4 "C2" "L1" "Rout" f^2 \[Pi]^2 - 
    8 I "C2" "L1" "L3" f^3 \[Pi]^3)]])/Log[10]
```

I want to calculate the derivative of Gain in order to Rin. Obviously when I do D[Gain,Rin] I get zero since the expression depends on "Rin" and not Rin. Then I try to do D[Gain,"Rin"] and it does not work as Mathematica does not derivate in order to strings. Finally I try to do D[Gain, ToExpression["Rin"]] but it does not work either, gives me zero. How do I do this effectively?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend not using strings as symbolic variables. The reason being, one is bound to stumble across this type of difficulty. (More generally, try to work with rather against the program. That of course holds for all large programs, not just this one.)

Comment: Why are you trying to do math with strings?

Answer (score 2):

```
D[Gain /. x_String :> ToExpression[x], Rin]
```

$$-\frac{20 \text{Rout} \left(-4 \pi ^2 \text{C2} f^2 \text{L3}+2 i \pi  \text{C2} f \text{Rout}+1\right) \text{Abs}'\left(\frac{\text{Rout}}{-8 i \pi ^3 \text{C2} f^3 \text{L1} \text{L3}-4 \pi ^2 \text{C2} f^2 \text{L1} \text{Rout}-4 \pi ^2 \text{C2} f^2 \text{L3} \text{Rin}+2 i \pi  \text{C2} f \text{Rin} \text{Rout}+2 i \pi  f \text{L1}+2 i \pi  f \text{L3}+\text{Rin}+\text{Rout}}\right)}{\log (10) \left(-8 i \pi ^3 \text{C2} f^3 \text{L1} \text{L3}-4 \pi ^2 \text{C2} f^2 \text{L1} \text{Rout}-4 \pi ^2 \text{C2} f^2 \text{L3} \text{Rin}+2 i \pi  \text{C2} f \text{Rin} \text{Rout}+2 i \pi  f \text{L1}+2 i \pi  f \text{L3}+\text{Rin}+\text{Rout}\right)^2 \left| \frac{\text{Rout}}{-8 i \text{C2} \text{L1} \text{L3} \pi ^3 f^3-4 \text{C2} \text{L3} \pi ^2 \text{Rin} f^2-4 \text{C2} \text{L1} \pi ^2 \text{Rout} f^2+2 \text{C2} i \pi  \text{Rin} \text{Rout} f+2 i \text{L1} \pi  f+2 i \text{L3} \pi  f+\text{Rin}+\text{Rout}}\right| }$$

Comment: Some explanations would be nice, can't find that x_String in documentation. Thank you.

Comment: I have converted anything that matches a `String` pattern called `x` to an expression. Search under `Pattern` or `Named Pattern` or `Blank`. I cannot think of an advantage of using such a construct while solving equations, but perhaps you can clarify it.

Comment: `Abs` is not differentiable. Prior to taking the derivative, use `ComplexExpand`. The form would also be simpler if constraints on the variables are included, e.g., many (all?) of the variables are presumably nonnegative or even positive.

Comment: @BobHanlon, Thanks for pointing out. Could you please write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Gain = (20 Log[
      Abs[("Rout")/("Rin" + "Rout" + 2 I "L1" f π + 2 I "L3" f π + 
          2 I "C2" "Rin" "Rout" f π - 4 "C2" "L3" "Rin" f^2 π^2 - 
          4 "C2" "L1" "Rout" f^2 π^2 - 8 I "C2" "L1" "L3" f^3 π^3)]])/
   Log[10];
```

Converting the strings to symbols,

```
Gain2 = Gain /. str_String :> ToExpression[str]

(* (1/Log[10])20 Log[
  Abs[Rout/(2 I f L1 π + 2 I f L3 π - 8 I C2 f^3 L1 L3 π^3 + 
      Rin - 4 C2 f^2 L3 π^2 Rin + Rout - 4 C2 f^2 L1 π^2 Rout + 
      2 I C2 f π Rin Rout)]] *)
```

[`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) is not differentiable. Prior to taking the derivative, use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html). The form would also be simpler if constraints on the variables are included, e.g., many (all?) of the variables are presumably nonnegative or even positive.

```
var = Variables[Level[Gain2, {-1}]]

(* {C2, f, L1, L3, Rin, Rout} *)

Gain3 = Assuming[var ∈ NonNegativeReals, 
  Gain2 // ComplexExpand // Simplify]

(* (1/Log[10])20 Log[
  Rout/(√((Rin - 4 C2 f^2 L3 π^2 Rin + Rout - 
         4 C2 f^2 L1 π^2 Rout)^2 + 
       4 f^2 π^2 (L1 + L3 - 4 C2 f^2 L1 L3 π^2 + C2 Rin Rout)^2))] *)

der = Assuming[var ∈ NonNegativeReals,
 D[Gain3, Rin] // FullSimplify]

-((20 (Rout + 
       Rin ((1 - 4 C2 f^2 L3 π^2)^2 + 
          4 C2^2 f^2 π^2 Rout^2)))/(((Rin - 4 C2 f^2 L3 π^2 Rin + 
         Rout - 4 C2 f^2 L1 π^2 Rout)^2 + 
       4 f^2 π^2 (L1 + L3 - 4 C2 f^2 L1 L3 π^2 + C2 Rin Rout)^2) Log[10]))
```